# AWS Kubernetes Cluster - WordPress Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I am novice person to  Kubernetes and trying to deploying WordPress and MySQL using the Kubernetes pod containers but its throwing the error "Error establishing a database connection" while running the Kubernetes .

[Wordpress Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn7W4.png)

[Overall Kubect status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jn7W4.png)

[AWS Inbound Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht7YZ.png)

**mysql-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: DEVOPS1
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: wpuser
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: DEVOPS12345
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: wpdb
```

**mysql-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
```

**wordpress-deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-deployment
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: wordpress
        image: wordpress
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: mysql-service
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
          value: wpuser
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          value: wpdb
        - name: WORDPRESS_DEBUG
          value: "1"
```

**wp-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Also I opened same thread on Kubernetes forum .  [Click Here](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/error-establishing-a-database-connection-error-kubernates-wordpress-mysql/15407/15) to view it

Comment: Do you have any more diagnostics on _why_ it can't connect?  Can you trim down the YAML files a little to be a [mcve] (for example, is the PersistentVolume required or even used; if you inline the host name rather than going via ConfigMap do you get the same error)?  When commands like `kubectl` write out plain-text output, can you include that directly in the question as text (not as an image, not behind a link)?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze , According to your advise. I updated my question. please read now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `containerPort` in your `mysql-deployment` file from `80` to `3306`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql-deployment
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: DEVOPS1
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: wpuser
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: DEVOPS12345
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: wpdb
```

Check similar problem: [wordpress-database-connection-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57769487/wordpress-error-establishing-a-database-connection-using-kubernetes).

Comment: I modified it . but same scenario is there ."Error establishing a database connection"  - https://snipboard.io/Xy2Wih.jpg

Comment: Did you check DNS to see if you could access the service from another pod?